# Removing Columns and Rows Corresponding to Zero Variables in $Ax=b$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading Logan's *A First Course in Finite Element Method* pg 182 where he shows a matrix multiplication such as,

[image]

Later he adds the assumption $\phi_1=0$, $v_1=0$ and $v_3=0$. As a result of this addition, he ends up with

[image]

which means he removed 1st, 2nd, 5th columns *and* rows from the matrix before the multiplication. Does this look like legit linear algebra? From a "multiplication is a weighted column combination" point of view, shouldn't the author remove only columns of the matrix corresponding to zero variables on the RHS?

Answer (score 1):

The finite element system of equations $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$ is only the end product. When applying the boundary conditions, you need to consider where the equation comes from.

**Example 1**

For example, if you use the principle of Minimum Potential Energy (MPE), you'd end up with the minimization problem

$$
\mathbf{x}=\min_{\hat{\mathbf{x}}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}}\frac{1}{2}\hat{\mathbf{x}}^{\top}\mathbf{A}\hat{\mathbf{x}}-\hat{\mathbf{x}}^{\top}\mathbf{b}
$$

which, for SPD matrix $\mathbf{A}$, the solution is also the solution to the equation $\mathbf{0}=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{b}$. Therefore, when you impose the homogenous Dirichlet boundary conditions, i.e. force some elements of $\mathbf{x}$ to zero, you remove the columns and rows associated with those elements in the minimization problem.

**Example 2**

Another example, if you use the principle of virtual work, you'd end up with

$$
\mathbf{0}=\delta\mathbf{x}^{\top}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}-\delta\mathbf{x}^{\top}\mathbf{b}
$$

for arbitrary $\delta\mathbf{x}$, which requires $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$. Therefore, when you set some elements of $\mathbf{x}$ to zero, which also means the same elements from $\delta\mathbf{x}$ must be zero too, it practically removes the rows and columns associated with the DoFs in $\mathbf{A}$.

Comment: Quick question: the name of the book has FEM in it, but the section I read was talking about a stiffness matrix and the example above is from a simple assembly of two matrices (two pieces). The section did not mention any energy approach, but maybe it is indirectly implied? My question is are there any non-FEM reasons columns and rows could be removed? Thanks for the response however.. I will keep it in mind.

Comment: @BBSysDyn the approach is used when formulating the element stiffness matrices. Assembly is simply gluing matrices together

Comment: I saw an example here pg 11, http://www.ce.memphis.edu/7117/notes/presentations/chapter_02.pdf using springs, similar problem, one variable is set to zero and both column and row is removed, because all $u_1$ related variables are gone, the remaining ones can be organized on the basis of $u_2,u_3$. He did not use a quadratic equation.